# App subscription confusion leads to billing

Tags: applications

I just downloaded an app yesterday and I accidentally agreed to the subscription which was about 100 dollars a year I cancelled it but now it says it expires next year so they billed me about $100. What do I do? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t say which App Store you purchased, but just go to the Apple Support app on iOS or web page - https://support.apple.com/ , select billing issues and refund.

[image: Accidental Purchase support from the iOS Apple Support App]

Explain your situation and see what can be done. The sooner you ask for help, the more likely you will get a result you like.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming you purchased through the App Store, make sure you have cancelled the subscription, and then request a refund from the App Store.
99% of the time the refund is almost immediate. It’s all on line, and just checking a few tabs. 5 minutes.